# Get count of triplets using RegEx

Tags: regex, match

Using RegEx how would you count triplicates in a string?

Example `122244445577777`

```
1 222 444 4 55 777 77
```

Answer `3`

Comment: Which language/tool? have you tried anything?

Comment: Its php

Tried this...

/1{3}|2{3}|3{3}|4{3}|5{3}|6{3}|7{3}|8{3}|9{3}|0{3}/ which works using  preg_match_all

Answer (score 1):

As the language/tool is not mentioned, I'll add the answer for some languages. However, the same RegEx can be used in any language with little or no modification.

```
([0-9])\1\1
```

Here, `([0-9])` will match a digit and put it in first captured group, which can later be accessed by using back-reference `\1`.

The same RegEx can also be written as

```
(\d)\1{2}
```

If you want to use this with any character and not just numbers, you can use following RegEx.

```
(.)\1\1
```

[**RegEx Live Demo on RegEx101**](https://regex101.com/r/gF1qJ7/1)

---

**Python:**

```
>>> s = '122244445577777'
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'(.)\1{2}', s)
['2', '4', '7']
>>> re.findall(r'((.)\2{2})', s)
[('222', '2'), ('444', '4'), ('777', '7')]
>>> len(re.findall(r'(.)\1{2}', s))
3
>>> len(re.findall(r'(\d)\1{2}', s))
3
```

**JavaScript:**

```js
var input = "122244445577777";
var regex = /([0-9])\1{2}/g;

var tripletCount = (input.match(regex) || []).length;
document.write(tripletCount);
```

**PHP:**

```
echo preg_match_all('/([0-9])\1{2}/', "122244445577777", $matches);
```

Comment: Why `(.)`. OP has clearly shown the input string that contains all numbers, use `([0-9])` or `(\d)`

Comment: ya.. his example shows only digits, but it's better to include the regex which uses dot also.

Comment: @Tushar Thanks for the edit, shall we have a talk? Here  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100886/jolly-talk

Answer (score 0):

In all the languages I know of you cannot do this with just a regex, you need to use some of the language's functions.

However the actual answer should be very short and uncomplicated. If you give us the language your using we can provide an actual answer.

In most languages it is probably simpler to do this without regex, as you need yo get the count of a random letter/number not a specific.

Comment: see my comment above yours

Answer (score 0):

After some frustration I arrived at this...

/1{3}|2{3}|3{3}|4{3}|5{3}|6{3}|7{3}|8{3}|9{3}|0{3}/

Must be a more elegant way? Its PHP btw which doesn't allow the g modifier

Comment: Didn't you read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34838508/2025923). Check the bottom of answer.